# Converting an os.system() to subprocess.call()

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm a little shaky on the syntax of subprocess.call command arguments when those arguments include combined strings of variables

I have 4 variables that are used in the single complete command-string that ran successfully using os.system:

- userPWD
- userName
- hostName
- path

  os.system("sshpass -p %s scp %s@%s:/var/tmp/*Metrics.csv %s" % (userPWD, userName, hostName, path))

Now converting that to subprocess.call which will give me the needed output status I need, the format of some aspects of this command-string is loosing me, as the subprocess.call documentation usually just shows very simple commands like this:

```
subprocess.call(['ls', '-l'])
```

My first effort to convert it looks like this:

```
subprocess.call(["sshpass", "-p", userPWD, "scp", "userName@hostName:/var/tmp/*Metrics.csv", path"])
```

but this produces the following error messages in Python 2.7.3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyprobeConnect.py", line 73, in <module>
    get_csvPassFail = subprocess.Popen("sshpass -p %s scp %s@%s:/var/tmp/*Metrics.csv %s" % (userPWD, userName, hostName, path)).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: You have unbalanced `"` characters in `["sshpass", "-p", userPWD, "scp", "userName@hostName:/var/tmp/*Metrics.csv", path"]`

Comment: Your traceback doesn't match your code.

Answer (score 2):

When you include `*` you need to pass `shell=True` and if you're passing `shell=True` you need to specify the first argument as a string not a list.

```
subprocess.call("sshpass -p %s scp %s@%s:/var/tmp/*Metrics.csv %s" % (userPWD, userName, hostName, path),shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks bernie, that was perfect.

Comment: Cheers, mate. Please accept this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I don't think using `shell=True` in the `subprocess` families is a good idea.  This is a very well-known vector of attack (or inconvenience).  The malicious (or clueless) user *may* inject arbitrary shell command.  In your case the password field seems to be in control of the user, so there could be a risk. The reason one refrains from using `os.system` is to prevent this kind of error.

Here, I presume you're using `scp` to pull files from the remote to the local host. In that case shell `*` globbing doesn't matter, because this is expanded by the remote shell.

Your stack trace says the problem is that the executable, in your case `sshpass`, cannot be located.  This is likely because the directory containing the executable isn't in your `PATH` environment variable.

To correct this, you can simply modify `PATH` temporarily as you call the command, in the following fake Python (you need to fill in your own details):

```
import os
cur_path = os.environ["PATH"]
if dir_of_your_executable not in cur_path:
    cmd_path = "%s:%s" % (dir_of_your_executable, cur_path)
else:
    cmd_path = cur_path
cmd_env = os.environ.copy().update(PATH=cmd_path)
subprocess.call(["sshpass", "rest", "of", "your", "command"], env=cmd_env)
```

The code will first check if the directory of `sshpass` is in the `PATH`.  If not, it is prefixed to the `PATH` and used for command execution.

Alternatively, just use the absolute path:

```
subprocess.call(["/path/to/sshpass", "rest", "of", "your", "command"])
```

Finally, a word of caution: Just say no to `sshpass`.  It's insecure, hence evil.  Use public-key based SSH authentication by starting `ssh-agent` before executing automated commands.  Dispense with passwords, especially passwords passed by `sshpass -p`.  They're evil.  Just Say No.